# rsync --exclude not excluding

Tags: backup, script, ubuntu-12.04, rsync, exclude

I'm using rsync on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with the following script to back up all of `/`, however, whenever I run the script (as root), the directory `/backup` is *included*, when it *should be excluded*:

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.password --delete -aAXzv --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found,/home/*/.gvfs,/home/*/Downloads/*,/backup/*,/var/spool/squid3,/opt/atlassian,var/www/\~*} /* fsbak@servername::fsbak
```

Why is this happening, and how can I make rsync ignore `/backup`?

Comment: /backup/* <- So rsync backs the content of the directory up as well and not just the directory itself?

Comment: Are the rest of the directories excluded correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` in the script has fixed this issue. The curly brace expansion used in the script is a `bash` feature and, as such, is not available in `sh`.